# commandButton issue in JSF

Tags: jsf-2

Brief intro about my requirement.

I have an empty JSF dataTable.
Now, when I click on a button, it should fill the empty datatable with data.

```
<h:commandButton value="Search" action="#{myBean.searchresults}" />
```

**Problem:**
When I click on the button, it populates the data to the dataTable but instantly shows me the same page when I load my application first time (refresh the page).
I want the page to *not refresh* itself and show the populated data.

I am stuck in this issue for the last 2 days.
Kindly provide your advice.

Thanks in advance!

Thanks,
Lee

Comment: Can you post some relevant code? THanks!

Comment: Please show some code! My best bet would be a wrong scope on your *@ManagedBean* or some messed up AJAX updates. Cheers!

Comment: Please find the code snippet:

Comment: Please show your ManagedBean-code (and please make sure its visible)! Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you want an asynchronous submit and a partial render? There the [`<f:ajax>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/) tag is for. 
 You can specify the submit context in `execute` attribute and the to-be-updated client IDs in `render` attribute.

E.g.

```
<h:form>
    <h:inputText value="#{bean.query}" />
    <h:commandButton value="Search" action="#{bean.search}">
        <f:ajax execute="@form" render=":results" />
    </h:commandButton>
</h:form>
<h:panelGroup id="results">
    <h:dataTable value="#{bean.results}" rendered="#{not empty bean.results}">
        ...
    </h:dataTable>
</h:panelGroup>
```

with

```
public void search() {
    results = service.find(query);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

do you have some navigation logic returned by `searchresults` ?

If not,

Make `searchresults` a void method

```
public void searchresults(){
//logic here
}
```

and add f:ajax to button

```
<h:commandButton value="Search" action="#{myBean.searchresults}" >
    <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form"/>
</h:commandButton>
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel for ur reply, now my issue has been solved... :)