# JSF 2 Explicit Navigation Datatable

Tags: jsf-2

We are in the process of moving to JSF 2 from JSF 1.x and I am was really looking forward to using many of the new features.  I have been searching around and can't seem to find either a reason and/or a solution to a problem I am having with explicit navigation where the h:commandButton is within a dataTable.

As you can see below the "Working" link properly redirects to the "testPage.xhtml" but the "NOT Working" link does not.  It just takes you back to the page you are currently on.  These pages exist in the same directory.

If this just doesn't work then fine, but I was curious if anyone has run into this issue and if there is a solution.

Project Info:

1. JSF 2.x
2. Facelet template surrounding form
3. RichFaces

For example, the following code is a sanitized subset of one of my pages:

```
    <h:form id="formListHome">
        <h:commandLink id="clWorkingExplicitLink" 
                    action="testPage.xhtml?faces-redirect=true">Working</h:commandLink>     

        <h:panelGroup id="pGrpExistingListUser" rendered="true">

            <h:panelGrid id="pGridListTable" columns="1">

                <rich:extendedDataTable id="edtLists"
                    value="#{listHomeBacking.modelUserLists}"
                    var="userList"
                    selectionMode="none"
                    columnClasses="pull-center, pull-left, pull-center">

                    <!-- List Title -->
                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="List Title" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:commandLink value="#{userList.titleName}" action="#{listHomeAction.previewList}" />
                    </h:column>

                    <!-- List Title -->
                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="List Edit" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:commandLink id="clNOTWorkingExplicitLink" 
                                    action="testPage.xhtml?faces-redirect=true">NOT Working</h:commandLink>     

                    </h:column>

                </rich:extendedDataTable>

            </h:panelGrid>
        </h:panelGroup>
    </h:form>
```

Any ideas or a direction that can be in helping to resolve this issue and gain a better understanding as to why it isn't working would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to get past this.  The issue existed within the code I had behind my page template.xhtml.  In this template backing code I was attempting to pull a UserSesion object (@SessionScoped) which had been set in session by a servlet using:

HttpSession session = (HttpSession) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSession(true);
this.userSess = (UserSessionTO) session.getAttribute("userSession");

and then manually push it back out to the session after changing some items by using:

FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestMap().put("userSession", userSess);

The problem was this was happening on every request and I believe ended up causing issues with my datatable being different for each request.

Not sure if I am supposed to do this in my answer or not, but I have to credit the following question/answer from this site in helping me to go back and see what the problem was.  I found it helpful after I posted my question, and it didn't exactly take me in the right direction, but it certainly did help.

[JSF 2.0 commandLink in datatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10454800/jsf-2-0-commandlink-in-datatable?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

The code seems correct, but the context may influence your result. Have you checket that the url-mapping for jsf page in web.xml is *.xhtml as your code suggest. If it were *.faces it would not work.

So you should have that :

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Not that :

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: When I first created the project I had *.faces as the mapping because it was the default from my project generation and it would just attempt to download my xhtml file.  I did a double check though just to be sure my servlet-mapping is correct and I do have it as you described above as *.xhtml.